# Slow Media Center Interface after Resume

Tags: windows-media-center, media-center

I have a Media Center PC connected to 52" LCD screen via HDMI. The problem I have is that even though I have high end specs on the box, the Media Center interface is slow and sluggish specially the first 30 - 60 seconds after the resume.

Are there any services I have to stop ? Is there anyway I can increase the response time so that my WAF goes high?

The specs are:

- [GA-MA790X-DS4H Motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/Products/Motherboard/Products_Overview.aspx?ProductID=2887)
- Onboard HD 3300 ATI Graphics Card with 128 MB of DDR3 RAM 1333 Mhz
- Sideport Memory 4GB of DDR 2 RAM
- Windows 7 Professional x86

Additional Software Installed

- MCE Standby Tool, it restarts MCE everywhere I resume
- Running the Latest Version of ATI Drivers
- EPG
- Win7 Codec Pack

Answer (score 1):

The following is the usual troubleshooting list I recommend for sleep problems:

1. Look in your BIOS for the suspend ACPI options and try to switch modes among "S1 and S3", "S3" etc.
2. [Turn off Hybrid sleep](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/turn-off-hybrid-sleep-in-windows-7/), see explanation [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-hybrid-sleep-mode/) (for vista, but is the same)
3. The hibernation file is sometimes disabled by disk cleaning, to restore do in cmd run as administrator "powercfg -h on".

Note: Any above manipulation that doesn't help should be undone.

You can use the following command to analyze sleep problems and return a detailed report:

> powercfg -ENERGY

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may just be usual. The fact is that during the resume process, certain system processes take place and the GUI / Video / Interface is lower priority that system processes.

If you really want to try, you can try going to task manager and setting the priority for the media centre higher, however I doubt this would work and I would not recommend it.